# How does the spell Longstrider interact with Gaseous Form?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The 3rd-level spell **[Gaseous Form](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gaseous-form)** states that you have a flying speed of 10 feet.

If you cast **[Longstrider](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/longstrider)** beforehand, does this in practice mean that your flying speed is effectively now **20 feet**?

I can't see why not, but I just wanted to confirm how these two spells interact first.

The background is that I can see this making quite a nice escape tactic, especially in a multi-class build with access to Cunning Action. If it works, it would mean, being able to move up to 60 feet upwards in a round.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I can’t see why not either

*Gaseous Form* gives you a flying speed of 10 feet (and takes away all your other speeds) and *Longstrider* increases speed by 10 feet.

As for it being a significant boost as an escape tactic, 20 feet is still pretty slow.

Comment: +1 Thanks for confirming this. I updated my question to add a little more information as to the speed while escaping. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes. Longstrider will increase a target's flying speed in Gaseous Form.**

As you mentioned, rules as written state that Gaseous Form has a flying speed of 10 feet. Longstrider increases a target's speed by 10 feet with no caveats.